# Unity 2D touch code destroying all objects?

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, touch

After looking for solutions to handle touch controls in Unity I found a solution that seems to work. Problem is, when a touch is detected, every single object with a 2D collider is destroyed. I only want the object that was touched to be destroyed.

Every Game Object in the scene is a prefab. They are all clones of 8 different random prefabs. Each of these prefabs has a Circle Collider 2D as well as the script for touch controls Called TouchManager.cs

I have tried changing the "if (hit)" portion to "if (hit.collider != null) but this causes it to not work for some reason. I have tried everything I could think of and nothing works!
Can anyone please help?

#### **TouchManager.cs**

```
// Update is called once per frame
void Update ()
{
    if (Input.touchCount > 0)
    {
        if (Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Began)
        {
            Vector3 wp = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.GetTouch(0).position);
            Vector2 touchPos = new Vector2(wp.x, wp.y);
            Collider2D hit = Physics2D.OverlapPoint(touchPos);

            if (hit)
            {
                touched = true;
                startPos = Input.GetTouch(0).position;
            }
        }   

        if (Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Moved)
        {

        }

        if (Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Ended)
        {
            if (touched == true)
            {
                float swipeDirection = Mathf.Sign(Input.GetTouch(0).position.y - startPos.y);

                if (swipeDirection > 0)
                {
                    Destroy(gameObject);
                }
                else if (swipeDirection < 0)
                {

                }

                // Reset touched
                touched = false;
            }
        }   //END SWITCH
    }   //END IF TOUCHED
}   //END UPDATE
```

Answer (score 1):

Whats happening here is that OverlapPoint returns the collider that the point overlaps, which means that you are checking: if the swipe overlaps any collider, destroy this gameobject.

What you want is to use hit.collider2D, it will store the collider2D that was overlapped. 
although hit.collider will always be null, that is because you dont have any colliders, you only have collider2D.

Since OverlapPoint tests against all colliders and dont care about what gameobject it is ran from, it better to place it in single manager object instead of each object and then let that manager destroy the other objects.

This code will destroy just one object. Remember to place it on a separate object from the ones you are destroying. I doubt it will give you a desired behavior but since i dont know what that is, i leave it as an exercise for you.

```
Vector3 startPos;
GameObject hitObject;

void Update()
{
    if (Input.touchCount > 0)
    {
        if (Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Began)
        {
            Vector3 wp = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.GetTouch(0).position);
            Vector2 touchPos = new Vector2(wp.x, wp.y);
            Collider2D hit = Physics2D.OverlapPoint(touchPos);

            if (hit != null)
            {
                hitObject = hit.collider2D.gameObject;
                startPos = Input.GetTouch(0).position;
            }
        }

        if (Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Ended)
        {
            if (hitObject != null)
            {
                float swipeDirection = Mathf.Sign(Input.GetTouch(0).position.y - startPos.y);

                if (swipeDirection > 0)
                {
                    Destroy(hitObject);
                }
                else if (swipeDirection < 0)
                {

                }
                hitObject = null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```